# New behaviours (with new XmlAttributes?) for XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

Is it possible to create new XmlAttributes that impose new behaviours on XmlSerializer?

Example, imagine i want to have a XmlAttrbute that indicates if a given field/property of a class is to be serialized at all if its value is null.

I know that, for this exemple you can use [Propert/Field]ShouldSerialize or [Property/Field]Specified or even XmlAttributeOverrides, but this approaches could mean tons of work.

Using a decompiler software i went to System.Xml.Serialization dll and opened classes like XmlIgnoreAttribute or XmlElementAttribute.

In XmlElementAttribute I found the following

```
public bool IsNullable {
    get { return nullable; }
    set { 
        nullable = value; 
        nullableSpecified = true;
    }
}
```

but unfortunatly the nullableSpecified  property in internal :( and I can't see if it would have the same effect has [Propert/Field]ShouldSerialize or [Property/Field]Specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't modify how XmlSerializer works.

What might be a viable workaround in your case would be to use some additional tool that would change your code at build time based on your custom attributes (to add those pesky `[Propert/Field]ShouldSerialize` members) - e.g. [Post Sharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) (to the best of my knowledge the free version is sufficient for your needs).

Comment: Hi @decPl, I'll see how postsharp can help. it should exist a way to change the behaviour :(

Comment: could I use IXmlSerializer with a custom Attribute and reflection?

Comment: @FEST - you could (with Reflection, it's pretty safe to assume the answer is "it's technically doable"), but the effort to write/stabilize/maintain that solution will far outweigh the cost of manually specifying those members.

Comment: You are right :S... you know what this makes me want to do? 
(incoming dumbest ideia..)
-generate System.Xml Project using a decompiler software
;change nullableSpecified somehow to be accessible
;compile and install on GAC (i think??)

but... even if this would work.... its really a stupid ideia :D

Anyway, thank you for the help @decPL.